# What causes -32601 errors when using the MailChimp API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

I'm using the hominid gem to interface with the MailChimp API, and my attempts at updating the content of a campaign are failing.

The code I'm using to update the campaign is:

```
h = Hominid::Base.new({:api_key => ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]})
h.update(self.mail_chimp_campaign_id, "content", {:html_content => content_string})
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
<-32601> server error. requested method not found
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the content I was trying to send to MailChimp. There were some special characters that MailChimp couldn't handle, and things worked fine after cleaning up the data I was attempting to send off.

While it didn't help me in my situation, I did read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mailchimp-api-discuss/pN0lDXnAeI4/tDvYdbSXXioJ) that converting the data before sending it off to MailChimp is a possible resolution. The suggestion is to take the data that's causing the issue, and run it through `Iconv` before sending it off to MailChimp:

```
utf8_to_ascii = Iconv.new("US-ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "UTF8")
utf8_to_ascii.iconv(gnarly_user_data)
```